# Export a LibreOffice Calc Chart to PDF witouth margins and empty space

Tags: pdf, graph, export, libreoffice

My aim is to export a LibreOffice Calc chart in PDF in order to use it with LaTex later.

I made a 16cm width and 9cm high graph. I would like to get a PDF without border and lot of empty space.

So I went to : file -> export as PDF-> **selection**...

However even with the selection option, I get a graph in a small pat of a A4 page with margins and empty space...

[image: Image 1/3]

[image: Image 2/3]

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Good question, since the settings are very misleading.

To my knowledge, it is not possible to directly save to pdf as you are hoping to do. However, there is a bit of a workaround that will still let you embed a vector graphs from Open/LibreOffice in your LaTeX documents:

1. Select and copy (ctrl+c) your graph.
2. Open LibreOffice Draw
3. Paste your graph from Calc into Draw
4. Select the graph, and go to `File --> Export`, select `EPS` from the list of formats, and make sure the `selection` box is checked:

[image]

I haven't tried the other formats, but EPS should play nicely with your LaTeX document, or you can easily convert your EPS to PDF and insert them.

Here is a side by side comparison of trying the export setting with PDF (left--ends up centered on the page) and EPS (right--exports just the graph).

[image]

Comment: Hello, 

Thank you for your answer is pretty fast and works nice. 

Thank you
 http://i.stack.imgur.com/UmXRo.png

Comment: @Swiss12000, Cool. I see from your profile that you have a couple of questions on the R tag. Any reason that you aren't creating these graphics in R and using Sweave or Knitr instead while writing your reports?

Comment: Hello yeah it's a good question. Actually, I'm a student. I try to adapt myself to the teacher. For some teacher - ie. marketing - I use LibreOffice or Excel to make simple graph because they are more colorfull. However, I use R graphs - via Sweave - for scientific paper or for homework such as statistics...

Answer (score 5):

I was faced to the same problem, and after trying different methods, I finally found a simple and great way to do that. Simply use the **pdfcrop** tool by tapping this simple command line:

```
    pdfcrop inputFile.pdf outputFile.pdf
```

Hope it will be helpful!